# Is there a way to force the second SIM to 4G?

Tags: mobile-data, dual-sim

My phone is Samsung M12, I want to know if I can switch the SIM 2 into 4G only. I know I can easily download 4G-only apps from Play store, but they work for the first SIM only. I need to force my second SIM to 4G only. Is this possible?

Comment: sorry but how can you use 4g on both sims since you can only use mobile data on one sim?

Comment: @Silent right. But I can be clumsy and sometimes too lazy if I have to switch the SIMs. Last time I wasn't careful enough, and the tray was broken. It's really comfortable if I don't have to unplug the tray and I can enjoy the 4g only on the second SIM.

Comment: Sorry i didnt see you mentiomed that you want to switch 2nd sim to 4g. I dont have an m12 but I can help you.

Comment: Found two videos which can solve specifically your problem. [This](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xjYc8neu7vQ) and [This](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mpCZBfB3cL0)

Comment: The second video is exactly what you need.

Comment: @Silent really nice and much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad could help